# Troubles Importing Clojure Libs in Paradise

Tags: clojure, slime, incanter

I occasionally get this problem, and generally work around it, but it's rather frustrating.

I have all of [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) (check it out if you don't know it: it's superb) on my classpath. I try to import it (through a Slime REPL) like this: `user> (use 'incanter.core)`, but fail.

Doing this: `user> (use 'clojure.contrib.def)` works just fine, and this file is in the same place–on my classpath.

Regardless, the error isn't anything about classpath: it's this:

```
Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

You can see my entire terminal **[here](http://cl.ly/1dU5)** (a screenshot.)

I don't know what's going on here, and it's really frustrating, as I really would like to use Incancter, and I can from the Incanter binary's REPL. I definitely don't want to develop from that–and this *should* work.

Any help would be *much* appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It appears as though Incanter [requires](http://wiki.github.com/liebke/incanter/) Clojure 1.2, and `lein swank` gives me Clojure 1.1. This might be the cause of my problems: if so, ***is there a way to continue to use Swank & Lein with Clojure 1.2***?

Thanks again!

**EDIT:**

Apparently if you start using Clojure-1.1 and `lein swank`, you're stuck with it unless you make a new project.

If future people have this problem, [this article helped me out](http://otfrom.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/leiningen-clojure-1-2-and-emacs/), but **also**, at least for me, **you must start a new lein project if you had begun it using `leink swank` and Clojure-1.1.** Simply changing your project.clj file and then `lein swank`ing again doesn't work.

Comment: What version of clojure are you running?

Comment: What version of lein are your using? As of version 1.0.1 of Leiningen, lein swank works correctly with Clojure 1.2 for me, but lein repl still uses Clojure 1.1. 

However, both lein repl and swank use 1.2 with latest version of lein (1.2.0-RC1).

Comment: I am using `Leiningen 1.1.0 on Java 1.6.0_20 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM. 

I finally have it working now, but I had to start a new project. Apparently if you start using Clojure-1.1 and lein swank, you're stuck with it unless you make a new project.

Comment: Not at all. You might need to run `lein clean` to remove the old 1.1 `jar`s from `lib/`, though (or just remove them by hand).

Comment: I did remove them–still had the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Leiningen and swank-clojure with Clojure 1.2. You might need to use a recent version of Leiningen (I'm not sure if a certain old limitation affected `lein repl` only or was it `lein swank` as well; anyway, try the 1.2-RC2 which you'll find in the downloads section on [GitHub](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen)). You will also need to use a recent-enough swank-clojure; I use a bleeding edge checkout myself, get yours [here](http://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure).

Other than that, simply use 1.2 jars for Clojure and contrib. (Lein uses it's own Clojure, separate from the one used for `lein swank`, for its internal workings and you never need to care about it; swank-clojure has no AOT'd namespaces and doesn't particularly care about the Clojure version, except once in a (long!) while something breaks, a patch is applied and joy is restored.)

I hope the above helps, but if it doesn't: your problem description is not entirely sufficient for me to get a clear picture of what is happening. Could you add information on what it means for "all of Incanter" to be on your classpath (do you mean the `jar`s? sources? where do you get them? how do you set your classpath?). Without knowing this, it'll be hard to replicate your setup to try to track down the source of the problem. 
Of course if bumping some versions fixes things, please disregard my current confusion. ;-)